# Loading html into bootstrap modal breaking jquery inside modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, template-engine

I am using a PHP framework (Fat Free F3) with a template engine to piece together the design I'm working on. The main template and all the .js files are being loaded on layout.htm. Inside of layout.htm, I have a link that when clicked, triggers the content of the url to be displayed inside of a bootstrap modal window. Below is that code:

```
<a href="/this/is/my/url" class="btn black mini icn-only" data-toggle="docs"><i class="icon-lock icon-large icon-white"></i></a>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('[data-toggle="docs"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
            $(url).modal('open');
        } else {
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                $('<div class="modal container hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="820"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button><h3 class="page-title">Title! <small> small txt</small></h3></div><div class="modal-body">' + data + '</div></div>').modal();
            }).success(function() { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Inside of this url (/this/is/my/url), I'm trying to use the bootstrap tooltip feature using the following code:

```
<button class="btn tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Tooltip in top">Top</button>
```

The tooltip does not show inside of the modal window, but it is working if I add it to the main page outside of the modal window. So my question is, how do I get tooltips (or any other bootstrap jquery events) to work inside of a modal window while using this template engine? Should I be reloading the bootstrap .js files inside of the modal window?

What's confusing me is the css seems to be working fine because the modal window contains a bootstrap table. I assumed the jquery would also work, but I'm obviously wrong.

Absolutely any feedback will help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your jQuery to initiate the `tooltip` since the element it is tied to isn't visible on page load :

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="docs"]', function() {
    $('.tooltips').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: adding $('.tooltips').tooltip(); in the else statement helped. I guess it needed to be initialized. I'm still new to jquery and I think I learned a valuable lesson here. Thanks so much for the response!!

Comment: It just needed to be initialized again because since the `.tooltips` in the modal are not present when the page is loaded, so they aren't initialized as are the ones on the page that are NOT in the modal.